# Why does linux shell diff command sometimes show output related to empty lines even though -B (--ignore-blank-lines) option is present?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, diff

Linux diff command accepts an option that instructs it to "ignore changes where lines are all blank", as per the manual page.

And while trying this option, I came across a situation where blank lines seem to not be ignored, even though -B (or --ignore-blank-lines) option is used.

Here follows a working script that demonstrates the issue:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e 'a\nb\nc' > file_a1
echo -e 'a\n\nb'  > file_a2

echo
echo \ file_a1
cat    file_a1
# a
# b
# c

echo
echo \ file_a2
cat    file_a2
# a
#
# b

echo
echo \ regular diff
diff    file_a1 file_a2
# 1a2
# >        <- output related to empty line
# 3d3
# < c

echo
echo \ diff -B : empty lines ignored, as expected
diff -B file_a1 file_a2
# 3d3
# < c

echo -e 'a\nb' > file_b1
echo -e '\nb'  > file_b2

echo
echo \ file_b1
cat    file_b1
# a
# b

echo
echo \ file_b2
cat    file_b2
#
# b

echo
echo \ regular diff
diff    file_b1 file_b2
# 1c1
# < a
# ---
# >        <- output related to empty line

echo
echo \ diff -B : same output, as if -B option was not present
diff -B file_b1 file_b2
# 1c1
# < a
# ---
# >        <- output related to empty line

echo
echo \ diff version
diff --version
# diff (GNU diffutils) 3.9
# Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
# License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
# This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
# There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
# 
# Written by Paul Eggert, Mike Haertel, David Hayes,
# Richard Stallman, and Len Tower.
```

Comment: The platform does not allow more than one answer to be accepted. So please take a look at Carlo Arenas' answer besides tripleee's accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the man page tells you, `-B` applies where the *only* changes are in whitespace. In your `file_b*` example, something changed into an empty line, so "lines are all blank" is untrue.

You could argue that the description is ambiguous, but this is what I believe it means.

Comment: In the script I provided, before showing the case where -B supposedly fails, it shows the diff between file_a1 and file_a2 — where something also changes into an empty line — and with -B the output related to this change does not appear on output.

Comment: So in other words a pair of changes where "nothing" changes to "whitespace" or vice versa, but there are no other changes in that hunk, will be suppressed with `-B`.

Comment: I got it.
Please disregard what I said in my previous comment stating in file_a*'s case "something also changed into an empty line". I get that's clearly not the case there.
I consider the question answered. Thanks!
(Next time I will pay due attention to users' reputation score :) )

Answer (score 3):

The whole reason behind -B is to avoid noise from "white space only" changes.  The description in the [FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?diff)/macOS man page is IMHO clearer as it describes "chunks" so it is clear that it is not meant to apply to single lines, specially if they only exist in one side of the comparison.

Your original assumption about what constitutes a change is incorrect, as it should ALSO include the type of change (those cryptic characters on top of the chunk), and which indicate how that change would apply.

You would notice that for your first test, the operation "adds" or "deletes" an empty line, but in the second pair, it "changes" a line and therefore as [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) explains in their answer it is not a "blank line only" operation.

Comment: Regarding the type of change, I realized the difference as of my second comment in @tripleee's answer, but indeed, till then I was not paying due attention to that.

Comment: Your answer clarifies and reinforces the point in matter. Btw, I was just looking for for some documentation regarding diff output format. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The platform does not allow more than one answer to be accepted, but if it did, I would accept yours as well. And, as of now, I still do not have enough reputation to up vote it. I'll do it when I am able to.